# android access to sql server through web service IIS or axis?

Tags: android, web-services, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5, axis

im new to stackoverflow so plesase forgive me if i commit any mistakes.
more to the point, im new to android and to web services. im making and android app thats supposed to communicate with an external db (sql server). and i realized its much wiser to do this through a web server. microsoft iis 7.5 is already installed on the server so my question is this. as im developing in java (eclipse) and knowing that iis is based on C am i obliged to learn iis or can i install and use forexample apache axis? which approach is simpler?
Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Hassan. Please take the time to read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page to help your question get a bit more attention. Browsing other questions and answers may help you get a feel for it as well. Learn to use the shift key when appropriate ;-), use proper spelling, grammar, and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

i've decided to just use iis as the webserver and learn a few scriplets to run on